# python selenium chrome.exe background process not killed after quit()

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, process, webdriver

I am having issue on several windows (7/10) OS with python 3.6.3 selenium latest version.

After I do the webdriver.quit() command the main chrome windows is closed, but several chrome.exe bg process don't.
I have a python scheduler rerun the method of opening chrome webdriver and closing it ... after few days the memory is full with chrome.exe process in bg.

More info:

- when I quit the python scheduler all the chrome bg process are gone.
- Tried to disable "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed”
- disabled sandbox mode
- instead of method call I run the the web-driver each time by sub-process
- not happens on all machines.

How can I make sure all subprocess are dead before I rerun ?

my code:

```
import schedule
import subprocess
import sleep

def job():
    command = ['python', 'chromeStartQuit.py']
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    print (process.returncode)

schedule.....
job()

while True:
    sleep(1800)
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Cancel no sandbox

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: see my comment sandbox